# Woocommerce product catalog, products with different description

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I am struggling to find a solution.
I am working on a Wordpress + Woocommerce project. The goal is to make a catalog, no prices, no orders, just products and subcategories.

I am now stuck at point where I can't find best way to show those products.

I have a product which has under it same product but different characteristics.
Example:

Product - vacuum cleaner "FAST series", it has 3 products under it (FAST 1X, FAST UBERX, FAST ULTIMATE) with different motors, sizes and thing that come in the box.

What would be the best way that when I open the product there are 3 choices and I choose depending on description or choose model from list? The title for all these 3 products would be "Vacuum FAST series".

If I use VARIATIONS then in detailed description it shows me all parameters for all models. But my goal is to show all variations in separate tables depending on model customer choose.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite an undertaking and difficult to answer thoroughly but this should help you on your way.

I would definitely stick with variations because it makes sense from a site structure and management point of view.

By default, WooCommerce will show information relevant to the option selected i.e. images, dimensions, description etc. That means when you select FAST 1X from the dropdown it will show everything related to that *If that's not working you'll need to investigate why but it'll be down to your custom theme.*

You'll more than likely need to tweak some of the WooCommerce templates to suit your layout, though. Overriding is the best way to do this as you won't lose any custom changes when the plugin updates and the best resource for this is: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ (For future readers: search 'WooCommerce template override' if the link is dead).

To override WooCommerce templates, copy the file from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/path/to/template/file.php` to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/path/to/template/file.php`. As long as the file path's match WooCommerce will load your override.

The `.content-single-product.php` template is a good starting point for changing the layout of the page and will allow you to see what hooks are being called. This will then let you remove any of them and add your own to tweak the layout of the page.

To add and remove hooks you need to add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function woocommerce_actions() {
    // Remove excerpt from product view
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

    // Optionally add it elsewhere
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

    // or hook your own function
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woocommerce_actions' );

function customer_template_single_excerpt() {
    return _e( "My custom excerpt", "custom-theme" );
}
```

Whilst vague this is the route you need to take and I'd recommend reading up on the various parts to get a better understanding of how to override and rearrange the layout.